# Converting a keras model to tflite model in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-lite

I saved a keras model with with following line of code

```
keras.save("saved_model.h5")
```

When I try to optimize and convert to a .tflite model using this code

```
converter=tt.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("saved_model.h5")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

I get this error

> ---
>
> ```
> ConverterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-23-faeb309a4cbc> in <module>()
> ----> 1 tflite_model = converter.convert()
>       2 with open("converted_model.tflite", "wb") as tffile:
>       3     tffile.write(tflite_model)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in
> ```
>
> convert(self)
>           896           input_tensors=self._input_tensors,
>           897           output_tensors=self._output_tensors,
>       --> 898           **converter_kwargs)
>           899     else:
>           900       result = _toco_convert_graph_def(
>
> ```
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py
> ```
>
> in toco_convert_impl(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, *args,
>   **kwargs)
>           402   data = toco_convert_protos(model_flags.SerializeToString(),
>           403                              toco_flags.SerializeToString(),
>       --> 404                              input_data.SerializeToString())
>           405   return data
>           406
>
> ```
> ~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py
> ```
>
> in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str,
>   input_data_str)
>           170       stderr = _try_convert_to_unicode(stderr)
>           171       raise ConverterError(
>       --> 172           "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
>           173   finally:
>           174     # Must manually cleanup files.
>
> ```
> ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
> /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516:
> ```
>
> FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
>       /home/scripter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550:
>   FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is
>   deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as
>   (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
>         np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/scripter/.anaconda3/bin/toco_from_protos", line 7, in 
>           from tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python.toco_from_protos import main
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.lite'

I am using tensorflow version 1.14.0. What could I be doing wrong

Comment: You should upload the exception with text not using an screen shot. But this issue maybe can help you: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/issues/108

Comment: Thanks @Guillem for the headsup. I will make the edits to that

Answer (score 0):

```
# We have our neural network trained with tensorflow and keras, we can export it 

saved_model_dir = '' #means current directory

tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_dir) #saves to the current directory

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) 
tflite_model = converter.convert() #converts our model into a .tflite model which flutter uses for ondevice machine learning

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f: #to write the converted model into a file, written as binary so add 'wb' instead of 'w'
  f.write(tflite_model)
```